# Finish all instances of an activity from all tasks?

Tags: android, android-activity

I have two tasks running.

Task 1:- ActivityA->LoginActivity(Instance1)

Task 2:- ActivityC->LoginActivity(Instance2)

When i finish LoginActivity(Instance2) on Task2, I need to finish LoginActivity(Instance1) from Task1.

How this is possible though any activity flag?

I tried with SingleTask launchMode, but as per docs this switches tasks, which dos not seems proper for the requirement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can register broadcast receiver to your login activity and finish the activity when you receive the close action, all your instances will receive the action and finish itselfs.